# Converting Earth-based observations to heliocentric coordinates using astropy SkyCoord

Tags: astropy, astronomy

I want to measure the parallax for a small solar system body (asteroid) between an observer at a specified location on planet Earth and the Sun.

I can measure the position from Earth (RA DEC). I know how far the asteroid is from the observer on Earth, but I am unsure of what frame class in the astropy coordinate package to use to hold the RA and DEC (and observation time and location) so that I can use the transform_to function to change those coordinates to the HeliocentricTrueEcliptic frame. Any suggestions and examples would be very much appreciated. Thank you!